# Is the number of steps obtained from the TYPE_STEP_COUNTER a purely hardware return?

Tags: java, android

I want to know that when I get the number of steps through the TYPE_STEP_COUNTER,the steps are pure hardware returned data, and not through the major phone manufacturers through their own algorithms returned

```
private void addCountStepListener() {
  Sensor countSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);
  if (countSensor != null) {
    stepSensorType = Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER;
    Log.d(TAG, "Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER");
    sensorManager.registerListener(StepService.this, countSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
  }
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    Log.d(TAG,"onSensorChanged");
    if (stepSensorType == Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER) {
        int tempStep = (int) event.values[0];
    }
}
```